# Sending & Accepting PayPal Payments through my PHP Website

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have my PHP Website where two different Category of users includes: Customers and Performers signed up. Now through my Website customers wants to pay via PayPal to Performers, Is there a way in PayPal to achieve this?

I have saved Performer's PayPal Email in my database, so I just want it work like PayPal payment buttons but with my own PayPal email and with my own Amount of money.

Ideas apart from PayPal are also warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

how about braintree. It support normal credit card payment gatemway and also paypal implementation

I think it is better to have normal credit card payment gateway and then implement paypal after that, cause I think all paypal user has credit card and not all credit card user has paypal.

Use this link for your reference to implement normal payment gateway, it should be very easy as they also provide sample code

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/start/overview

And you can continue to implement paypal after that using this link for reference

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/paypal

Comment: I am so new to this World of Payment Gateway's Implementation. I just wish I can have all type of payment systems in my Website just like Freelancing Sites. And I thought the simplest way must be PayPal, I will look into BrainTree, And I hope things will sort out,